# PHP - Get values from XML content

Tags: php, xml, foreach, xml-parsing

See below, the XML body I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/393999/sync/logistics/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">SalesItemPrices</title>
    <link rel="self" title="SalesItemPrices" href="SalesItemPrices" />

    <entry>
        <id>https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/393999/sync/logistics/SalesItemPrices(2781117417L)</id>
        <title type="text"></title>
        <updated>2021-08-11T11:47:22Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit" title="SalesItemPriceSync" href="SalesItemPrices(2781117417L)" />
        <category term="Exact.Web.Api.Models.Sync.Logistics.SalesItemPriceSync" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:ItemCode>OX11213001-M61</d:ItemCode>
                <d:Price m:type="Edm.Double">136.36</d:Price>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/393999/sync/logistics/SalesItemPrices(2781117419L)</id>
        <title type="text"></title>
        <updated>2021-08-11T11:47:22Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit" title="SalesItemPriceSync" href="SalesItemPrices(2781117419L)" />
        <category term="Exact.Web.Api.Models.Sync.Logistics.SalesItemPriceSync" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:ItemCode>EK1117005.58</d:ItemCode>
                <d:Price m:type="Edm.Double">164.46</d:Price>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I need to get the values : **ItemCode & Price** for each entry.

I tried to do so like this :
$data = **simplexml_load_string($xml)**, but when I do print_r($data->entry), here is what I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/393999/sync/logistics/SalesItemPrices(2781117417L)
    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text
                )

        )

    [updated] => 2021-08-11T13:47:01Z
    [author] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

    [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [rel] => edit
                    [title] => SalesItemPriceSync
                    [href] => SalesItemPrices(2781117417L)
                )

        )

    [category] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [term] => Exact.Web.Api.Models.Sync.Logistics.SalesItemPriceSync
                    [scheme] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme
                )

        )

    [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [type] => application/xml
                )

        )

)
```

But I expected to have :
**<d:ItemCode>OX11213001-M61</d:ItemCode>
<d:Price m:type="Edm.Double">136.36</d:Price>**
in the "content" part.

Then, how can I get these values? and also how to correctly make a loop between these all "entry"?

I tried foreach **($products->entry as $product)**
but received error : **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work. Please note that your elements are namespace-d and have a prefix.

```
$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$myResult  = [];

foreach($simpleXML->entry as $entry) {
$properties = $entry->content->children('m', true);
$myResult[] = ['itemCode' => (string) $properties->children('d', true)->ItemCode, 'itemPrice' => (string) $properties->children('d', true)->Price];
}

print_r($myResult); // to see the values
```